# Error when trying to deploy: The bundle currently has capybara locked at 2.2.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capybara

I have a Ruby on Rails web application that I am trying to deploy.

When I try to deploy it, it gets a little ways, and then stops with the following error:

```
** [out :: rails-rn-dev.sandia.gov] You have requested:
** [out :: rails-rn-dev.sandia.gov] capybara = 2.1.0
** [out :: rails-rn-dev.sandia.gov] 
** [out :: rails-rn-dev.sandia.gov] The bundle currently has capybara locked at 2.2.1.
```

I can't figure out how this is happening.  I know that both my Gemfile and my Gemfile.lock files specify capybara version 2.1.0 be used.

So, why is the bundle locking capybara at 2.2.1?

Thanks in advance,
Tim

Comment: do bundle show capybara to ensure you have the version you think you have.  Also, are you running cap within bundle? (bundle exec cap ...)?

Comment: Thanks - I ran bundle show capybara; I believe it indicates I'm running version 2.1.0/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@asset_manager2/gems/capybara-2.1.0.  I also tried bundle exec cap deploy - same result.

Comment: look at the Gemfile.lock and see if capybara "2.2.1" is there. According to the message, it is. Make sure you have this in you Gemfile -  gem "capybara", "2.1.0"  after that do "bundle update capybara" and try deploying again

Comment: Yep - I'm positive the Gemfile.lock file doesn't have capybara 2.2.1 anywhere in it.  I even tried deleting the Gemfile.lock file.  And I also have gem "capybara", "2.1.0" in my Gemfile, and have done multiple "bundle update Capybara" commands.  Still the same thing.